# Module not found stops Truffles from running test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am learning solidity by making a Defi app, I am trying to run a test on my solidity contracts but I get this error:

```
PS E:\Ethereum\2nd tutorial\defi_tutorial> truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\src\contracts\DaiToken.sol
> Compiling .\src\contracts\DappToken.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Local\Temp\test--5492-GXGirlunlBMI
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/lib/breadcrumb'
Require stack:
- E:\Ethereum\2nd tutorial\defi_tutorial\test\TokenFarm.test.js
- C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js
- C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\index.js
- C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Ethereum\2nd tutorial\defi_tutorial\test\TokenFarm.test.js:8:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at loader (E:\Ethereum\2nd tutorial\defi_tutorial\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (E:\Ethereum\2nd tutorial\defi_tutorial\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:384:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:381:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:954:10)
    at C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\test.js:159:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\h2001\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\test.js:158:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Node v14.15.1
```

I went to npmjs and looked for "react-bootstrap-breadcrumbs" and installed the best match with all of its dependencies but I still get the same above error when I run `truffle test`.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and fixed it by changing the `react-bootstrap` dependency version from `1.0.0-beta.5` to `1.0.0-beta.4`.

You can change it in your `package.json` file in your project folder.

Then don't forget to do an `npm install` before running `truffle test` again.